# Cannot access secondary GPU Bumblebee (Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, bumblebee

- When running `optirun glxgears`, I get:

  ```
  [ 1211.541206] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not load GPU driver
  [ 1211.541351] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
  ```
- When running `lspci -k | grep VGA`, only the internal GPU shows up:

  ```
  00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
  ```
- The secondary GPU only appears as a 3D controller when running *lspci -k | grep 3D*

  ```
  03:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1341 (rev a2)
  ```
- [as requested by comments]

  `dpkg --get-selections | grep nvidia`:

  ```
  bumblebee-nvidia                install
  nvidia-304                  install
  nvidia-current                  install
  nvidia-settings                 install
  ```
- [Contents of `/etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf`](http://pastebin.com/7Vty15Re)

Comment: What is the output of `dpkg --get-selections | grep nvidia`? Also can you post the contents of `/etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf`? (you can use http://paste.ubuntu.com/)